# Abrir iframe ao clicar e descarregar ao fecha-lo

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando implementar em um portal com receitas, despesas, etc. Estou usando `iframes` para trazer as informações do servidor. Funciona bem, até que percebi que se carregar todos os `iframes` todos de uma vez ele embaralha as funções de cada `iframe` porque quando carrega um `iframe`, ele carrega todos dentro da função.
Necessito então de um código que faça o `iframe` abrir no momento do clique e descarregue ao fecha-lo.

```
    window.onload = function() {
    //Receitas
    document.getElementById("iframe1").src="LINK_IFRAME1";
    document.getElementById("iframe2").src="LINK_IFRAME2";
    //Despesas
    document.getElementById("iframe3").src="LINK_IFRAME3";
    document.getElementById("iframe4").src="LINK_IFRAME4";
    document.getElementById("iframe5").src="LINK_IFRAME5";
    document.getElementById("iframe6").src="LINK_IFRAME6";
}
```

No html estou trazendo eles assim:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ingresso-de-receitas">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" class="blank" title="Fechar" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Ingresso de receitas</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <iframe id="iframe1" width="100%" height="900px" frameborder="none"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

1° Crio o `modal` normal, agora onde vai ficar o `iframe` que no caso era no `modal-body` deixei assim:

HTML

```
<iframe width="100%" height="900px" frameborder="none"></iframe>
```

No JavaScript usei assim:

```
$('#MyModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
$('#MyModal iframe').attr('src','LINK EXTERNO OU INTERNO');
})
$('#MyModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
$('#MyModal iframe').removeAttr('src');
})
```

Desta maneira o `modal` abre, carrega link e ao fechar o `modal` descarrega o `iframe`.

Funciona muito bem pra quem usa sites de videos. E não deixa o site pesado ao carregar a pagina no começo, só carregando o `modal` no momento que estiver aberto.